# Spring Batch Single Input Line to Multi Line Output

Tags: java, json, spring-batch

I have a json responses file as input need to convert it to csv. 
Input file contains more than 1000 lines of responses. Each response contains more than one client information. Requested output is each line must be one client information

ex: one line of input

```
{"monitoringMessage":{"type":"SEED","messageId":"eaf2f4d1-ccaa-4ca2-baa3-130aceac9c48_5","messageTimestamp":"2015-12-11T09:31:48.040Z","inLanguage":"en-US","reference":"Duns_notif","notificationCount":1,"notifications":[{"organization":{"isExporter":false,"name":"xyz","age":"34"},{"organization":{"isExporter":false,"name":"abc","age":"40"}]}}
```

expected output(csv format):

```
xys,34
abc,40
```

Can any one suggest on this using Spring-batch?

Answer (score 1):

First you'll need to read the json file. For that you can use a [`FlatFileItemReader`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemReader.html) combined to a [`JsonLineMapper`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/mapping/JsonLineMapper.html) and a [`JsonRecordSeparatorPolicy`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/separator/JsonRecordSeparatorPolicy.html).

```
<bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <property name="resource" value="${input.file.location}"/>
    <property name="recordSeparatorPolicy">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.separator.JsonRecordSeparatorPolicy" />
    </property>
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.JsonLineMapper" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then you'll need a [`FlatFileItemWriter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemWriter.html) to write the csv file.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter" scope="step">
    <property name="resource" value="${output.file.location}"></property>
    <property name="lineAggregator">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
            <property name="delimiter" value=","></property>
            <property name="fieldExtractor" ref="fieldExtractor"></property>
        </bean>                                 
    </property>
</bean>
```

Since the `JsonLineMapper` will return a `Map`, you either need an `ItemProcessor` to convert this `Map` to a bean with your attributes (name, age) that'll let you use a [`BeanWrapperFieldExtractor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/transform/BeanWrapperFieldExtractor.html) as your `lineAggregator`; or you can use a `FieldExtractor` that lets you get Map values by indexes.